# Indy returning odd content-type for certain messages. How solve?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

There is this particular kind of Amazon message that seems to throw Indy's MessagePart parser.

The message is structured (strongly abridged version, of course) as such:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
       boundary="----=_Part_853547_18414509.1354745829993"

<some irrelevant header stuff>

------=_Part_853547_18414509.1354745829993
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
       boundary="----=_Part_853548_20128671.1354745829993"

------=_Part_853548_20128671.1354745829993
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<the message in plain text>

------=_Part_853548_20128671.1354745829993
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<the message in HTML>

------=_Part_853548_20128671.1354745829993--

------=_Part_853547_18414509.1354745829993--
```

Now, when I perform a

```
imap.UIDRetrieve(UID,Msg)
```

then

```
Msg.ContentType = "multipart/mixed"
```

and the individual `Msg.MessageParts` have this as content-type:

```
Msg.MessageParts[0].ContentType = "multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_Part_853548_20128671.1354745829993""

Msg.MessageParts[1].ContentType = "text/plain"
```

No trace of the `text/html` part.

Would anyone have any idea what is going on here?

(am using very latest Indy build)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I run that email data as-is directly through `TIdMessage` using the current Indy 10 SVN snapshot, it parses just fine.  Three `MessageParts` entries are generated - `multipart/alternative`, `text/plain`, and `text/html` - as expected.

In [your recent post to the Embarcadero forum](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=515651) on this same subject, you left out a key piece of information - you are using `TIdIMAP4` to retreive the emails that are failing for you.  That is important because the portions of the email that you consider irrelevant must be containing data that is hitting a piece of Indy code that has a known design limitation that will not be fixed in Indy 10 (but is already marked as required for Indy 11) but which affects `TIdIMAP4`.

Internally, `TIdIMAP4.UIDRetreive()` passes the raw downloaded email as-is to `TIdMessage.LoadFromStream()`.  The core parser inside of `TIdMessage` expects the input data to be escaped using an SMTP-style dot transparency that IMAP does not actually use.  `TIdMessage` currently does not have any way of knowing the source of the input email data, and consequently its formatting for escaped data.  It is the responsibility of higher level protocol transports to parse and decode escaped data as needed, and then should pass the unescaped data to `TIdMessage` for further parsing.  But that is not actually the case right now.  That separation of logic is not in place in Indy 10 as much as it should be.  `TIdMessage` uses direct access to the source data, which works fine in `TIdSMTP` and `TIdPOP3` but not in `TIdIMAP4`.

In the `IdMessageClient.pas` unit, there is a helper class named `TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg` that has a public `EscapeLines` property that was specifically designed to help address this issue in situations that need it (namely, passing un-escaped data to `TIdMessage.LoadFrom...()` methods).  Instead of calling `TIdMessage.LoadFromStream()` directly, the current workaround is to instantiate a `TIdMessageClient`, assign a `TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg` to its `IOHandler` property, set its `EscapeLines` property to True, and pass it the source `TStream` to parse and destination `TIdMessage` to output to.  This allows Indy to fake the escaping formatting that the core parser is expecting to unescape.

<strike>However, `TIdIMAP4` does not currently utilize this workaround yet.  Now that I think about this, it should be easy to add, so I will look into it.  In the meantime, you can use `TIdIMAP4.RetrieveNoDecodeToStream()` or `TIdIMAP4.UIDRetrieveNoDecodeToStream()`, which will indirectly escape the data when writing to the destination `TStream` (another known design limitation that needs fixing), and then you can pass that `TStream` to `TIdMessage.LoadFromStream()` to parse normally.</strike>

**Update**: I have just checked in an update to the `AppendMsg()` and `InternalRetrieve()` methods of `TIdIMAP4` to no longer rely on SMTP-style dot transparency.  This has been on Indy's TODO list for several years now, so it is nice to final address it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Remy. I have installed the latest update (is it correct that all sources are dated Aug 10? Hard to find the changed sources.) In any case, the update didn't change anything in this case. Do I apply that striken-through paragraph?

Comment: Update: I had installed the latest update from the fulgan ZIP (which was dated Dec 10), but noticed that all source files were dated Aug 10. I then proceeded to check the SVN trunk and discovered that the sources are far more recent there. Plucked the necessary sources from there and recompiled. All is working fine now! Thanks, but the fulgan ZIP is *very* misleading!